# A proof that $|x+yi|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, based on the given the conditions

Tags: complex-numbers, definition, absolute-value

If we attempt to *define* $|x+yi|$ by following conditions:

1. $|x|=|xi|=x\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ (implicitly meaning the result will always be $\ge 0$)
2. $|xz|=|x||z|$
3. $|z^x|=|z|^x$

for  $x \in \mathbb{R}, z \in \mathbb{C}$. (Note that the definitions of $x$ and $z$ apply to all three conditions listed, not just the last one.)

I want to prove for all real $x$ and $y$ that $|x+yi|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, but proofs that only apply to subsets of all of the possible real values of $x$ and $y$ are welcomed (I show one proof below that proves $|x+xi|=\sqrt{2x^2}$). 
I've managed to quite easily prove that $|1+i|=\sqrt 2$:
$$|1+i|=? \\ |(1+i)^2|=|1+2i-1|=|2i|=|2|=2 \\ |1+i|=\sqrt2$$
However, the moment I start to generalise to $|x+i|$, $|1+xi|$ or $|x+yi|$, I am incapable of getting rid of the imaginary component on the right-hand side.
$$|x+i|=?\\|(x+i)^2|=|x^2+2ix-1|$$
From then on, no matter how much I try to manipulate the equation, I can't get rid of the imaginary component on the right hand side, same case with $|x+iy|$ and $|1+xi|$. (I don't know if I'm missing something or if there's some way of manipulating the equation that I don't know about.) I generalised $|1+i|=\sqrt{2}$ to $|x+xi|=\sqrt{2x^2}$ by using the same method I used on $|1+i|$ (by taking advantage of the "mutually annihilative terms" when multiplying out the brackets):
$$|x+xi|=? \\ |(x+xi)^2|=|x^2+2x^2i-x^2|=|2x^2i|=|2x^2|=2x^2 \\ |x+xi|=\sqrt{2x^2}$$

[Edit by OP] I recently have found this generalised "polar" form, in case it is of use to proving $|x+yi|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$:
For $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$,
$$|i|=1 \\
|i^y|=1^y=1 \\
|xi^y|=x$$

---

**Restating the question for clarity**:

Assume that the function $f:\Bbb{C}\to\Bbb{R}_{\ge0}$ satisfies the criteria

1. $f(x)=f(ix)=|x|$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R}$,
2. $f(xz)=f(x)f(z)$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R},z\in\Bbb{C}$, and
3. $f(z^x)=f(z)^x$ for all $x\in\Bbb{R},z\in\Bbb{C}$.

Then prove that $f(x+iy)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for all $x,y\in\Bbb{R}.$

[Edit by OP] For the third condition, note that if the ambiguity with multiple roots become a problem, you may restrict the answer to $\sqrt[x]{z}$ to the root which gives the complex number with the smallest non-negative $\theta$ component when describing complex numbers using the polar coordinate system (as in: $xi^y$).

Comment: I feel like you could just define $|\cdot |$ the usual way on the coordinate axes, and $0$ elsewhere, and it would still satisfy $|x| = |ix| = x\operatorname{sgn}(x)$ for all real $x$, yet obviously not be the usual absolute value overall. Meaning, you need different assumptions/properties.

Comment: @pjs36: well, that's not completely true. The OP did manage to show that $|1+i|=\sqrt{2}$, so one cannot assign the value $0$ to $|1+i|$. We can compute the absolute value using this definition if it's angle to the real axis is a rational multiple of $\pi$.

Comment: You happened to get lucky with $|1+i|$ in that $(1+i)^2=i\cdot(1+i)(1-i)$. That’s not going to happen in general, so no amount of manipulation is going to “get rid of the $i$’s.” The basic problem you’re having is that squaring a complex number does square its absolute value, but produces something that points off in a completely different direction.

Comment: @vrugtehagel Yes, I spoke too soon :) OP, I edited because I think people don't quite understand your question, hence the downvotes. If I've misinterpreted what you're asking, please feel free to roll back.

Comment: Just wanted to mention, that the OP could only show $\lvert 1 + i \rvert = \sqrt{2}$ because he assumed $\lvert x^2 \rvert = \lvert x \rvert^2$, which was not stated previously.

Comment: @menag I didn't even realise that I assumed that... now that I realise my "accidental assumption", is it a valid assumption to make?

Comment: If you assume $\lvert x^2 \rvert = \lvert x \rvert^2$, then you can drop the assumption $\lvert ix \rvert = x \operatorname{sgn}(x)$. Anyway, if the assumption is "valid" cannot really be answered. We already saw an answer which shows that your given assumption ($\lvert x \rvert = \lvert ix \rvert = x \operatorname{sgn}(x)$) are not sufficient to determine the absolute value. In fact, there are even more absurde possibilities, i.e. $f(x) = x \operatorname{sgn}(x)$ and $f(ix) = x \operatorname{sgn}(x)$ for real $x$ and $f(z)$ can be chosen arbitrary for non-real and non-imaginary complex number

Comment: I've added my implicit assumption such that it is now explicitly stated.

Comment: God of Llamas, I tried to reformulate the question in the end. I replaced the use of absolute value with the function $f$, because that confused some users, at least initially. But exactly what can the answerers assume in condition 3? If it holds for all real exponents, then the question becomes easy, because it easily follows that $f(e^{i\alpha})=1$ for all $\alpha\in\Bbb{R}$. OTOH if it only holds for integer exponents, you probably get bizarre counterexamples. Where is this question from? Did you start thinking about this yourself? Please comment further.

Comment: All: I deleted some comments trying to extract a more specific question from the OP. It seemed to me that those points were already satisfactorily (?) addressed. Some other unclarity about the assumptions may remain.

Comment: I only added the bounty because the answer to this question is of high interest to me, and thus I want to get an answer (I do not have the necessary understanding of maths and so on to answer the question myself). I believe this should be an okay use of a bounty (I've never used one before though, so I can't be sure).

Comment: In the restatement for clarity at the end of your post, condition (3) is problematic: if $x \in \Bbb R$ and $z \in \Bbb C$, it is *not* always possible to define $z^x$ (if $z=-1$ and $x=\frac 1 n$, which of the $n$ roots do you define to be $z^x$? this can be solved by removing a half-line from $\Bbb C$, choosing a branch of the complex logarithm and defining $z^x = \textrm e ^{x \log z}$). You should clarify this point.

Comment: @AlexM. Hmm...good point, but does it matter? I mean that in that the conditions that I am hoping will characterise the absolute value function mean that $|xi^y|$ is not dependent on $y$ ($x$ and $y$ are real). In what case would this ambiguity be a problem?

Comment: I have edited the question now. Hopefully that will eliminate the ambiguity with multiple roots.

Comment: I've noted that you haven't accepted a single answer to any of the 6 questions that you have asked here so far. This kind of attitude won't go unnoticed here, and people will begin avoiding you and no longer answering your questions. Please think about it, and remember that this community is volunteer-based: we are not paid for our work here, reputation points are our only symbolic reward. This doesn't mean that you should blindly accept no matter what answer if it doesn't meet your standards, but I am sure that among the answers that you have already received so far there are a few good ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, as it has been restated now, your question can be answered in the affirmative (ignoring details such as the fact that $z^x$ cannot be defined for just any $x \in \Bbb R$ and $z \in \Bbb C$).

First, assume that $|z|=1$ and $z \ne 1$. Then, there exist $t \in (0, 1)$ such that $z = \textrm e ^{2 \pi \textrm i t}$. Note that

$$z^{\frac 1 t} = \textrm e ^{\frac 1 t \log z} = \textrm e ^{\frac 1 t 2 \pi \textrm i t} = \textrm e ^{2 \pi \textrm i} = 1 ,$$

so from conditions (1) and (3):

$$1 = |1| = f(1) = f(z^\frac 1 t) = f(z) ^{\frac 1 t} ,$$

so $f(z) = 1^t = 1 = |z|$.

If $z = 1$, then $f(z) = f(1) = |1| = |z|$ from condition (1). So far, we have proved that if $|z| = 1$, then $f(z) = 1 = |z|$.

Now, if $z \ne 0$ then $\frac z {|z|}$ has modulus $1$, so we may apply the result from the above paragraph to deduce that $f \left( \frac z {|z|} \right) = 1$, and using condition (2) we obtain

$$f(z) = f \left (|z| \frac z {|z|} \right) = f(|z|) f \left( \frac z {|z|} \right) = |z| \cdot 1 = |z| .$$

Finally, if $z=0$ then condition (1) gives $f(0) = 0 = |0|$ trivially.

We have thus proved that $f(z) = |z| \ \forall z \in \Bbb C$.

(Note that the part $f(\textrm i x) = |x|$ from condition (1) was not needed, it can be deduced from (3) and the other part of (1).)

Comment: The only reason I have not accepted this answer is you haven't given me the answer to "Then prove that $f(x+iy) = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$." You've proved that $f(z)=|z|$, which is good and I appreciate it but what about the proof that $|x^2+y^2|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$? Sorry it's been a while in terms of replying (I haven't gone on SE for quite a while), and I do not mean to be dismissive of answers or anything like that, it's just that they didn't really answer my question. (I admit it was vague in the beginning, but that's why I refined the question)

Comment: @godofllamas: Frankly, I don't understand: if I have already proven that $f(z) = |z|$ (where $|z| = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is the usual modulus of $z = x + \textrm i y$), isn't is obvious to you that $f(x + \textrm i y) = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$?

Comment: Yes, it is obvious, but where do we get the equation of $|x+iy|=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$? You've proved that $f(z)=|z|$ (for all $z \in \mathbb{C}$) and consequently $f(x+iy)=|x+iy|$ by substitution, but then how do you deduct that $f(x+iy)$ which is $|x+iy|$ is equal to, for all $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ without invoking the definition? (Sorry for any potential vagueness, but I can't quite find the words for it...)

Comment: Let me use italics, maybe this will make things clearer. There is *the usual modulus function* (the one that you learn in school), that is denoted $|x + \textrm i y|$ and that is, by definition, $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. There is, then, *your own new modulus function*, that is denoted $f(x + \textrm i y)$ and that, in principle, we do not know how to express. My proof above shows that, in fact, the two functions are equal, whence it follows that *your own modulus function* is equal to $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ (the usual modulus).